# Need assistance Fixing Some coding in this Java Class File

Tags: java

So im new to Stack Overflow and hope I am saying this question correctly.
I was given this assignment from class and was done with it until my professor tweak the assignment a little bit. In summary i made 2 classes the would work with each other and call off the variable from the other class into the class it was being called to. Now my professor want 1 java file which mean one class file. I do not know how to rewrite the program with both code into one class.

Assignment:

> "(The Location class) Design a class named Location for locating a maximal value and its location in a two-dimensional array. The class contains public data fields row, column, and maxValue that store the maximal value and its indices in a two-dimensional array with row and column as int types and maxValue as double type.
>    Write the following method that returns the location of the largest element in a two-dimensional array:
>
> public static Location locateLargest(double[][] a)
>
> The return value is an instance of Location. Write a test program that prompts the user to enter two-dimensional array and displays the location of the largest element in the array. Here is sample run:
>
> Enter the number of rows and columns of the array: 3 4
>   Enter the array:
>   23.5 35 2 10
>   4.5 3 45 3.5
>   35 44 5.5 9.6
>   The location of the largest element is 45 at (1, 2)

SO i did all that with the 1st class coding:

```
public class Location {

        int row;  //blue variable = class variable
        int column;
        double maxValue;
}
```

Then here the code that call in the program in the second class

```html
import java.util .*;

public class TestLocation {

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  Location mylocation;
  int row; 
  int column;
  double [][] numArray; //we can leave this blank
  Scanner Reading = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println(" How many rows will you be entering?");
  row = Reading.nextInt(); //nextInt -what it reads will convert into a integer
  
  System.out.println(" How many columns will you be entering?");
  column = Reading.nextInt();
  
  numArray = new double [row][column];
  
  System.out.println("Enter the array please");
  
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {
   for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
   {
    numArray[i][j] = Reading.nextDouble();
    //i is the row and j is the column
   
   }
   
  }
  mylocation = locateLargest(numArray);
  
  int temp = (int)mylocation.maxValue; //this is to print out the difference between int and double(decimal)
  if (temp == mylocation.maxValue)
   System.out.println("Highest Number: " +(int)mylocation.maxValue); //(int forces to be an integer then the double it was, eliminate decimal places)
  else
   System.out.println("Highest Number: " +mylocation.maxValue); //print out with decimal
  System.out.println("Position: (" + mylocation.row+", " + mylocation.column +")");
  
  
  Reading.close();
 }
 
 
 
public static Location locateLargest(double[][] a)
  
  {
   
   Location mylocation = new Location(); //this is where we are going to store my information in
   mylocation.maxValue = a[0][0]; //this is the max value to the first number
   mylocation.row = 0;
   mylocation.column = 0;
   
   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) //Length of the row; how many row there are
   {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) //Length of a row; how many column in that row
     //we added array here in the second because we want of get the length of the second dimension
     //.length get the length of the current dimension , so a.length get the length of the first dimension
    {
     if (mylocation.maxValue < a[i][j] )
     {
      mylocation.maxValue = a[i][j];
      mylocation.row = i;
      mylocation.column = j;
     }
     
    }
    
   }
   
   return mylocation; 
   
  }

}
```

how can i reprogram this with the new instruction that was in the assignment box above that require me to but all the coding into one class = 1 java file? I tried almost everything And could not get the results i want.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the answer to your question. I was looking at JavaScript questions and saw yours. You shouldn't tag JavaScript when your question is about Java.  

JavaScript !== Java

Answer (score 1):

One java file only allows one public class file. Remove public keyword from the first java file, and put them into the same file as the second one will work.

```
class Location {
    int row;  //blue variable = class variable
    int column;
    double maxValue;
}
```